# How to perform multiplicative inverse in C#

Tags: c#, biginteger, modulo

I have the following code:

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(12345678912345678912);
var modedInteger = b * 3712931 % (2 ^ 64);
```

Given this, how would I get the value of `b` **from** `modedInteger`? I saw that we can use `BigInteger.ModPow()` but I am not sure...

Comment: No, it doesn't answer how to get b with a multiplication, in my case I am multiplying b with 3712931

Comment: ... divide the result by 3712931?

Comment: but then what do I put inside of my Mod.Pow() function? I tried putting what they put but I get 1 as the output

Comment: Note, that `2 ^ 64 == 66`, since `^` stands for **xor** (e**X**lusive **OR**), not for "2 in 64th power"

Comment: _"I saw that we can use BigInteger.ModPow() but I am not sure"_ -- why not? Where did you "see" that, and why are you "not sure"? Your question lacks important details that would explain what you've tried, why that didn't work, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Because the second argument of ModPow() requires a exponent and I don't have an exponent

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks for that heads up!

Comment: @King A: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try starting from **Extended Euclid Algorithm**, e.g. (let it be implemented as *extension methods*)

```
    public static (BigInteger LeftFactor,
               BigInteger RightFactor,
               BigInteger Gcd) Egcd(this BigInteger left, BigInteger right) {
      BigInteger leftFactor = 0;
      BigInteger rightFactor = 1;

      BigInteger u = 1;
      BigInteger v = 0;
      BigInteger gcd = 0;

      while (left != 0) {
        BigInteger q = right / left;
        BigInteger r = right % left;

        BigInteger m = leftFactor - u * q;
        BigInteger n = rightFactor - v * q;

        right = left;
        left = r;
        leftFactor = u;
        rightFactor = v;
        u = m;
        v = n;

        gcd = right;
      }

      return (LeftFactor: leftFactor,
              RightFactor: rightFactor,
              Gcd: gcd);
    }
```

Then you can continue with *mod inversion* and *mod division*:

```
    public static BigInteger ModInversion(this BigInteger value, BigInteger modulo) {
      var egcd = Egcd(value, modulo);

      if (egcd.Gcd != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid modulo", nameof(modulo));

      BigInteger result = egcd.LeftFactor;

      if (result < 0)
        result += modulo;

      return result % modulo;
    }

    public static BigInteger ModDivision(
      this BigInteger left, BigInteger right, BigInteger modulo) =>
           (left * ModInversion(right, modulo)) % modulo;
```

Finally, your test:

```
  BigInteger b = new BigInteger(12345678912345678912);

  //DONE: Please, note that ^ stands for XOR, so 2 ^ 64 == 66
  BigInteger mod = BigInteger.Pow(2, 64);

  var modedInteger = b * 3712931 % mod;

  BigInteger result = modedInteger.ModDivision(3712931, mod);

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 12345678912345678912
```